# Cannot convert System.Data.Datarow to System.DateTime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, type-conversion

I have a Datatable and DataRows in it, and those DataRows gets the value from a XML file.

```
DataRow row = table.NewRow();
row["InvoiceNumber"] = xmlData.ChildNodes[2].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[2].ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
row["InvoiceIssueDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(xmlData.ChildNodes[2].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[2].ChildNodes[1].InnerText);
row["InvoiceDeliveryDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(xmlData.ChildNodes[2].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[2].ChildNodes[2].InnerText);
```

But when I want to add those rows to my Entity Framework table that's error comes.

```
Invoices invoices = new Invoices();
invoices.InvoiceNumber = table.Rows[0].ToString();
invoices.InvoiceIssueDate = table.Rows[1];
invoices.InvoiceDeliveryDate = table.Rows[2];
```

How should I convert them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
invoices.InvoiceIssueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(table.Rows[1]);
invoices.InvoiceDeliveryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(table.Rows[2]);
```